# converting to a sprintf() query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, printf

Working traditional query:

```
$form_id = Caldera_Forms::get_field_data( '_entry_id', $form ); 
$post_id_qry = mysql_query("SELECT `meta_value` FROM wp_cf_form_entry_meta WHERE entry_id = '$form_id' and meta_key = 'ID'");
$post_id = mysql_fetch_array($post_id_qry);
echo $post_id['meta_value'];
```

Now when I convert over to a sprintf() to make it more secure and it returns blank. I have tried a syntax check and it came back clean. Any ideas?

```
$form_id = Caldera_Forms::get_field_data( '_entry_id', $form );
global $wpdb;
$post_id_qry = sprintf("SELECT `meta_value` FROM %s WHERE entry_id = %d and meta_key = 'ID'", $wpdb->prefix . 'cf_form_entry_meta', $form_id ); 
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results($post_id_qry);
echo $post_id['meta_value'];
```

Comment: Try echo'ing the resulting $post_id_qry and see what it says. Then run it in the database, to make sure you're getting a correct query.

Comment: you are getting correct query and your code is right i think.

Comment: you need to make sure that you are getting proper value in form id and proper value in table and other related from and where clause.

Comment: Why do you think converting to `sprintf` will make it any more secure? If you want to prevent SQL-injection, you should use a prepared query or escape the user-supplied values. Using `sprintf()` doesn't do either of those things.

Answer (score 0):

`$wpdb->get_results()` returns an array of all the results of the query, not just a single row. And by default the rows are objects, not associative arrays. So you need to do:

```
echo $post_id[0]->meta_value;
```

to display the value.

If you want to get a single row as an associative array, use:

```
$post_id = $wpdb->get_row(ARRAY_A);
echo $post_id['meta_value'];
```

Note that WP doesn't have anything analogous to `mysql_fetch_array`. The options to `get_row` are `ARRAY_A`, which is like `mysql_fetch_assoc`, and `ARRAY_N`, which is like `mysql_fetch_row`.